# Add a delimiter to an integer in Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So let's say I have a number like `123456789` and I want to convert it to a string and present it as `123,456,789` or `123 456 789` and etc. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think there's a built in way. For general formatting you can use [`:io.format/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-2) Here's one way to do it:

```
123456789
|> Integer.to_char_list
|> Enum.reverse
|> Enum.chunk_every(3)
|> Enum.join(",")
|> String.reverse

# "123,456,789"
```

Edit: here is a solution that also works for decimals. It optionally allows setting custom separators:

```
defmodule Formatter do
  @doc """
  ## Examples

      iex> Formatter.format_number(1)
      "1"

      iex> Formatter.format_number(123)
      "123"

      iex> Formatter.format_number(1234)
      "1,234"

      iex> Formatter.format_number(123456789)
      "123,456,789"

      iex> Formatter.format_number(-123456789)
      "-123,456,789"

      iex> Formatter.format_number(12345.6789)
      "12,345.6789"

      iex> Formatter.format_number(-12345.6789)
      "-12,345.6789"

      iex> Formatter.format_number(123456789, thousands_separator: "")
      "123456789"

      iex> Formatter.format_number(-123456789, thousands_separator: "")
      "-123456789"

      iex> Formatter.format_number(12345.6789, thousands_separator: "")
      "12345.6789"

      iex> Formatter.format_number(-12345.6789, thousands_separator: "")
      "-12345.6789"

      iex> Formatter.format_number(123456789, decimal_separator: ",", thousands_separator: ".")
      "123.456.789"

      iex> Formatter.format_number(-123456789, decimal_separator: ",", thousands_separator: ".")
      "-123.456.789"

      iex> Formatter.format_number(12345.6789, decimal_separator: ",", thousands_separator: ".")
      "12.345,6789"

      iex> Formatter.format_number(-12345.6789, decimal_separator: ",", thousands_separator: ".")
      "-12.345,6789"
  """

  @regex ~r/(?<sign>-?)(?<int>\d+)(\.(?<frac>\d+))?/

  def format_number(number, options \\ []) do
    thousands_separator = Keyword.get(options, :thousands_separator, ",")
    parts = Regex.named_captures(@regex, to_string(number))

    formatted_int =
      parts["int"]
      |> String.graphemes
      |> Enum.reverse
      |> Enum.chunk_every(3)
      |> Enum.join(thousands_separator)
      |> String.reverse

    decimal_separator =
      if parts["frac"] == "" do
        ""
      else
        Keyword.get(options, :decimal_separator, ".")
      end

    to_string [parts["sign"], formatted_int, decimal_separator, parts["frac"]]
  end
end
```

Comment: Works great for me! Is util for formating numbers in Phoenix templates

Comment: Where would you put that in Phoenix application, so that you can reuse it in your views?

Comment: Usually you would just create a `MyApp.Util` module in your lib/ directory where you can put your little helper methods. If you see patterns and/or things that belong together more closely, you can later extract a specialized module from there.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work reliably if the large numbers also have an arbitrary number of decimals (the commas are inserted among the decimals as well).

Comment: @EgeErsoz Well until now this was only about integers. Actually you should get an `ArgumentError` if you try to put in a decimal in there. You can extract the integer part of decimal numbers though and chunk it up afterwards, see edit.

Comment: Yes, I apologize, I didn't mean to imply your answer was incorrect. It works perfectly for Integer inputs. I just arrived via a Google search and in my use case I'm dealing with large Decimals (i.e. currencies), so I wanted to note that for others in my situation. :)

Comment: @PatrickOscity is there a way to transfor the decimal devider (in this case ".") to a (",") which is used in some countries in Europe? I have a hard time with regex...

Comment: @tomr please check my updated answer, this should be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. That works amazingly. Any chance you can explain why you need to reverse the enum? I am getting the rest of the function, but not that part.

Comment: @tomr sure thing. The `chunk_every` builds the 3-digit chunks from left to right, but we need it the other way round. So I reverse the digits first, build the chunks, then reverse the result again. Try removing both reversals, then feed it an input with a number of digits that is NOT evenly divisible by 3. E.g. `12345678` would result in `123,456,78` but we want `12,345,678`.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for taking the time to explain this to me! Much appreciated!

Comment: Hey Patrick, I hope it is not too annoying yet, but it doesnt work for negative numbers and I have not found an elegant solution yet (besides a case/cond). Do you have an idea how to do this in an elegant way?

Comment: @tomr sure so the sign needs a separate pathway because otherwise it ends up being treated like a digit and there will be an extra separator between the sign and the highest digit. Check my edit for a solutions that extracts the three parts (sign, integer and fractional part) using a regex. I added a few doctests which should cover all major edge cases now.

Comment: @tomr well thanks for finding flaws in my code :D